# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen "abschließen", "absolvieren" und "bestehen"?

Tags: difference

Ich möchte verstehen, was der Unterschied zwischen "abschließen", "absolvieren" und "bestehen" ist. All diese Wörter haben die gleiche Übersetzung in meiner Sprache! Wann wird jedes von ihnen verwendet?

Danke!

Comment: Willkommen bei German.SE. Bitte um folgende Ergänzung: Beispiele! Z.B. Sätze, die in der eigenen Sprache auf (wie auch immer die Übersetzung heißt) enden. Beispiele, wo in der eigenen Sprache ähnliche und somit andere Worte als (wie auch immer es in der Übersetzung heißt) verwendet werden: dadurch kann deutlich werden, warum es auch im Deutschen unterschiedliche Worte gibt. Denn die eigene Sprache kennt meistens auch verschiedene Wörter für ähnliche Situationen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Abschließen** legt das Augenmerk auf die Beendigung einer Aktivität, die sich über eine gewisse Zeit erstreckt hat. Man kann zum Beispiel sagen

> Ich habe den Deutsch-Kurs abgeschlossen.

Der Kurs hat vielleicht ein halbes Jahr gedauert, aber jetzt ist er vorbei, und man hat ihn beendet. Bildlich gesprochen kann man sich vorstellen, dass der Kurs während des halben Jahres "offen" war. Indem man den Kurs beendet hat, hat man ihn "geschlossen" oder "abgeschlossen", ein wenig wie eine Tür.

"Abschließen" alleine sagt eigentlich noch nichts darüber aus, ob man etwas *erfolgreich* beendet hat. In der Regel wird das jedoch impliziert, das heißt,

> Ich habe den Deutsch-Kurs abgeschlossen.

bedeutet in den meisten Fällen so viel wie

> Ich habe den Deutsch-Kurs erfolgreich abgeschlossen.

**Bestehen** bezieht sich auf eine Aufgabe oder eine Herausforderung, die man gemeistert hat. Es wird oft im Zusammenhang mit Prüfungen verwendet. Bildlich gesprochen kann man sich vorstellen, dass jemand versucht, einen umzuwerfen (etwa mit schwierigen Fragen in der Prüfung). Man ist aber "stehen geblieben", man hat "bestanden".

> Ich habe die Prüfung am Ende des Deutsch-Kurses bestanden.

**Absolvieren** ist ähnlich wie "bestehen", aber etwas allgemeiner. Wenn man etwas "absolviert hat", hat man es durchgeführt. Das sagt noch nichts darüber aus, ob man auch erfolgreich war. Man kann zum Beispiel sagen

> Ich habe die Prüfung drei mal absolviert, und beim dritten Mal habe ich (sie) bestanden!

In einigen Fällen wird auch mit "absolvieren" bereits "erfolgreich absolvieren" impliziert, das ist aber nicht immer der Fall.

Comment: Sehr schön und simpel erklärt.

Comment: Ja, absolvieren und abschließen kann man auch Kurse oder Tätigkeiten wie ein Praktikum oder Training, die keine Abschlußprüfung haben.

Comment: Irgendwie vermisse ich erbsenzählend die Tatsache, dass z.B. Abschließen weitere Bedeutungen hat, z.B. eine Tür abschließen - auch wenn sich das mit dem "abgeschlossenen Kurs" praktischerweise deckt. Ansonsten vermisse ich an der Antwort nichts und da es um den Zusammenhang dieser drei Wörter geht ist auch klar, welcher Bedeutungsaspekt gemeint ist.

Answer (score 2):

"Bestehen" hat mehrere Bedeutungen, aber im Kontext von "abschließen" und "absolvieren", handelt es sich wohl um folgende Bedeutung: **eine Prüfung oder einen Test bestehen**, d.h. bei der Prüfung oder dem Test Erfolg haben (meistens in dem man eine ausreichende Zahl von Punkten erreichend). Beispielsatz: "Sie hat die Prüfung mit der Note 'gut' bestanden."

Das Gegenteil von "bestehen" ist "durchfallen".

**Absolvieren** (z.B. eine Schule, einen Kurs oder einen Lehrgang absolvieren) bedeutet, dass man eine Schule, einen Lehrgang o.ä. erfolgreich beendet. Eine Person, die z.B. das Studium an einer Hochschule absolviert ist ein Hochschulabsolvent oder eine Hochschulabsolventin. Die Hochschule organisiert für ihre Absolventen und Absolventinnen eine Absolventenfeier.

Man kann allerdings auch eine Prüfung absolvieren, d.h. die Prüfung ablegen und bestehen.

Man kann eine Schule oder ein Studium **abschließen**, d.h. (erfolgreich) beenden. ("Abschließen" ist in diesem Kontext fast ein Synonym für "absolvieren"; "absolvieren" ist allerdings förmlicher.) Man kann aber auch eine Masterarbeit "abschließen" (d.h. beenden) oder ... "absolvieren".